# Sublime Text package similar to NppExec?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-2, nppexec

Anybody know of a package for Sublime Text 2 that will let me execute a shell command, save shell commands, run the currently-open file?

I miss the utility of NppExec from Notepad++, in which I would save something like:

```
irb -r "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

...press F6, Enter, and I'd be rolling. With Sublime Text 2, I've got to get out a shell, navigate to the right directory, then enter the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build system to define whatever commands you want to be executed. Checkout the [official documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) for more information on how to perform what you want.

Comment: When I give it the `"cmd": ["irb"]`, it tells me `[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`. I've read the documentation, but I see no help. I suppose it's not possible to get an interactive environment this way?

Comment: That error means the same as if you typed "c:\SgtPooki\something\thisDOESNTexist\file.cs". Basically your command syntax is probably correct but you have the wrong file/filepath.